# VB.net - Get the "real" character on PreviewKeyDown/KeyPress Event from e.Key

Tags: regex, vb.net, events, keyboard

I'm facing some difficulties building my inputfilter for a TextBox (WFP, but this should not matter here)
I need to suppress all inputs, but:
-Digits (Integer - no floats, groups)
-Basic Math Symbols: (,),+,-,*,/

Yes, the goal is to have a kind of formula evaluation. This part works well with the Sriptcontrol-Method
(from: http://www.vb-tips.com/Eval.aspx)
I also found several leads to filter by Regex (sorry, can't remember the source...):

```
 Regex("[\d\(\)\+\-\*\/]")
```

Now the problem is, that e.g. the Character '+' never shows up in the e.Key Argument
 
Pressing NumPad-'+' gives me  
e.Key=85  
e.Key.Tostring=Add

Trying from Keyboard '+'  
e.Key=141  
e.Key.ToString=OemPlus

So the Regex will never find a match to these allowed chars.
Since Windows recognizes the Key I hit and places the Character I see on my Keyboard, I guess, there MUST be a way to catch "exactly" the Key, which the user means to hit :-)
Also I needed to suppress any modifier-chars (such as AltGr+2: square on my german layout)

Here my Code Pasted (might be a little bit messy due to experimenting around)

```
        Private Sub tb_PreviewKeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles TB0.PreviewKeyDown
        Dim s As TextBox = sender
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Key.ToString & " -" & e.Key)
        Dim rx As New Regex("[\d\(\)\+\-\*\/]|Add|Subtract|Divide|Multiply|Return|Tab|Back")
        If Not rx.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString) Then
            e.Handled = True
            Return
        End If
        If e.Key = Key.Enter Or e.Key = Key.Tab Then
            If s.Text.Trim = "" Then Return
            If Not IsNumeric(s.Text) Then
                Try
                    Dim ev As New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
                    ev.Language = "VBScript"
                    ev.AllowUI = False
                    ev.Reset()
                    s.Text = CStr(Math.Round(CDbl(ev.Eval(s.Text))))
                    s.SelectAll()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    s.SelectAll()
                    e.Handled = True
                    Return
                End Try
            End If
            s.SelectAll()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Any hints on this are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: That isn't possible to do reliably, keyboard layout and state is critical.  Use the PreviewTextInput event instead.

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot, this did the trick! Have both events handled: TextInput blocks the user for entering garbage, PreviewKeyDown makes the evaluation! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of Hans Passant solved my issue!